# power function without the use of math library

Tags: c, floating-point, microcontroller

I'm working on a micro-controller that contains access to floating-point operations.

I need to make use of a power function. The problem is, there isn't enough memory to support the pow and sqrt function. This is because the microcontroller doesn't support FP operations natively, and produces a large number of instructions to use them. I can still multiply and divide floating point numbers.

***Architecture***: Freescale HCS12 (16-bit)

Comment: I assume that the power contains a fractional part, right?

Comment: How much precision do you need ?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, correct.

Comment: @PaulR Not much, 3 decimal places would work really.

Comment: So approximate `log` and `exp` functions should do it then - I recommend http://www.amazon.co.uk/Math-Toolkit-Real-Time-Programming-Crenshaw/dp/1929629095 for these

Comment: its not clear if this handles fractional powers, but this approximation may be of use: http://martin.ankerl.com/2007/10/04/optimized-pow-approximation-for-java-and-c-c/

Comment: @PaulR Sorry if I wasn't too clear, using the math library with FP numbers produces too many instructions.

Comment: Well, there's http://www.jhauser.us/arithmetic/SoftFloat.html or 
http://www.6502.org/source/floats/wozfp1.txt … What kind of µcontroller is it?

Comment: @BRPocock Freescale HCS12 (16-bit)

Comment: @seljuq70: just to clarify: see the Crenshaw book I linked to above for good approximations for log and exp which you can combine to implement a sufficiently accurate pow for your needs without too many instructions. You can use fixed point or floating point, according to your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mentioned the architecture, you might get a more specific answer.

The linux kernel still has the old x87 IEEE-754 math emulation library for i386 and i486 processors without a hardware floating point unit, under: `arch/x86/math-emu/`

There are a lot of resources online for floating point routines implemented for PIC micros, and [AVR libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/) has a floating point library - though it's in AVR assembly.

[glibc](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/) has implementations for `pow` functions in `sysdeps/ieee754`. Obviously, the compiler must handle the elementary floating point ops using hardware instructions or emulation / function calls.

Comment: Sorry, I changed my question now. HCS12, ints are defined as 16-bit.

Comment: @seljuq70 - ah. That makes my answer a little heavy. I just read the above comments - they look like better hacks for what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Make your own function that multiplies repeatedly in a loop.

Comment: This may be too slow work when the power is too high, and will not work at all if the power contains a fractional part.

Comment: Yeah, you will have to make some sacrifices.  There's a reason the built-in power function takes up too much space.  You won't be able to get full functionality with less code.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The speed is not any of my concern, I just want it to fit.